# Why non-extensive terms cancel out in the low temperature expansion of 2d Ising model?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, ising-model, partition-function

I'm currently reading David Tong's lecture on [Statistical Physics](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/statphys.html), and I cannot understand the logic in the following paragraph about the low temperature expansion of 2d Ising model.

---

[image]

It can be obtained by diagrammatic calculation that $Z = 2 e^{2N\beta J} \left(1 + N e^{-8 \beta J} + 2N e^{-12 \beta J} + \frac{1}{2} (N^2 + 9N) e^{-16 \beta J} + \ldots \right)$. I can understand the whole thing so far.

But why does the $N^2$ term disappears in the expansion of $\log{Z}$ ? Is it because that those other terms which is omitted in the expansion of $Z$ cancel this $N^2$ term?

Comment: It is the reminiscence of the linked cluster theorem. Yvan has already pointed that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally? This follows from the expansion of $\log(1+x) = x -\tfrac12 x^2 + \dots$, since

\begin{align}
\log &\bigl( 1+Ne^{-8\beta J} + 2N e^{-12\beta J} + \tfrac12(N^2+9N)e^{-16\beta J} + \dots\bigr)\\
&= \bigl(Ne^{-8\beta J}\! + 2N e^{-12\beta J}\! + \tfrac12(N^2+9N)e^{-16\beta J}\! + \dots\bigr) - \tfrac12 \bigl( N^2 e^{-16\beta J}\! +\dots \bigr) +\dots \\
&= Ne^{-8\beta J} + 2N e^{-12\beta J} + \bigl(\tfrac12(N^2+9N) - \tfrac12 N^2\bigr) e^{-16\beta J} + \dots \\
&= Ne^{-8\beta J} + 2N e^{-12\beta J} + \tfrac92 N e^{-16\beta J} + \dots
\end{align}
The omitted terms only contribute to orders higher than $e^{-16\beta J}$.

Of course, (1) the above argument does not explain why only terms linear in $N$ remain at all orders, (2) it lacks rigor (the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $\log(1+x)$ is $1$, so that the expansion does not a priori makes much sense when $N$ becomes very large (even if $\exp(-\beta J)$ is very small) and (3) it does not explain why/how such an expansion applies to the infinite-volume free energy density.

The rigorous proof of a much more general claim (the so-called *cluster expansion*) can be found in Chapter 5 of [this book](https://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook). The specific application to the low-temperature Ising model is treated in Section 5.7.4.